# No Persistance Provider for EntitiyManager named "tableName"

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I am having problems running an example application in NetBeans. I've connected successfully with database but when I run it says this this:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Hotel_CrudPU
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
>       at DAL.EntMngClass.(EntMngClass.java:16)
>       at DAL.HotelRepository.(HotelRepository.java:8)
>       at GUI.View.HotelForm.(HotelForm.java:29)
>       at GUI.View.MainForm.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainForm.java:166)
>       at GUI.View.MainForm.access$000(MainForm.java:11)
>       at GUI.View.MainForm$1.actionPerformed(MainForm.java:50)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

The persistance looks like this, and also I am using EclipseLink for Persistance and not Hibernate. 
[image]

[image]

P.s. I dont know what more information you need but for anything else please just leave a comment! Thanks.

EDIT: I added libraries that I am using.

Comment: Update your question with a link to the "example application" you are using.

Comment: @skomisa I've fixed the problem. Thank you anyway!